# Show that the supremum of a function is finite and that is a norm on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $C(K,\mathbb{R}^M)$ denote the vector space of all continuous functions from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}^M$. Show that for $f$ in $C(K,\mathbb{R}^M)$, the quantity $\| f \|_\infty = \sup_{x\in K}\| f(x)\|_2$ is finite and $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ is a norm on $C(K,\mathbb{R}^M)$.

I'm not really sure how to go about this one, I know intuitively that since the dimention of $\mathbb{R}^M$ is finite, the subset should also have a finite dimension and so the norm has to be finite but isnt that obvious, or is there something i am not seeing? also I'm unfamiliar with the notation $\| f(X)\|_2$, why is there a 2 in subscript?

Any help would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the fact that every real-valued continuous function from a compact set obtains a maximum? Then you can use the fact that the function $x\mapsto \|f(x)\|_2$ is continuous to show that $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is equal to that maximum value (and thus finite).

As for the subscript 2, there are many choices of norm for $\mathbb{R}^M$, in particular, the one you are taking $\|v\|_2=\sum_{i=1}^{M}|v_i|^2$, where $v=(v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_M)$. The 2 is from the fact that you're squaring.

EDIT: As commented, statement was false without compactness.

Comment: ...obtains a maximum on a compact set.